# Immutable Object Patterns for Domain Models

Tags: c#, immutability

I'm trying to introduce immutable types into our code base and I'm trying to determine a good pattern that is intuitive for our team. I was reading about [the Popsicle pattern](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability/) and that seemed complicated. I also saw a lot of builder patterns. But those seemed like overkill as well. In the example below I would like to make the FlexSession object immutable to guarantee it is always in a valid state.

The immutable part I'm particularly trying to determine a good pattern is in the Controller below. Since FlexSession is immutable, I added a Create function that will clone the FlexSession object and in doing so will update the properties. I've seen other examples of using builders to construct the new object, but I struggled to see how that might work to compare the merits of the other pattern.

My basic architecture is an MVC controller calls a repository to query for an object. The controller updates the object and sends the object back into the repository to persist the changes.

In the repository there is a service that talks with DynamoDb. I am considering putting a conversion from the document object to a domain object. Where the domain object is immutable.

**DynamoDb Document**

```
public class FlexSessionDocument
{
    public string SortKey { get; set; }

    public List<int> PriceTypes { get; set; }
}
```

**Repository**

```
public class Repository
{
    private readonly Service service;

    public Repository(Service service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public FlexSession Get(string sessionKey, string packageId, string token)
    {
        var query = BuildQueryByKeys(sessionKey, packageId, token);

        var model = this.service.Get<FlexSessionDocument>(query);

        return new FlexSession(model);
    }

    public void Update(FlexSession session)
    {
        var sortKey = BuildKey(session);

        var model = new FlexSessionDocument();

        model.SortKey = sortKey;
        model.PriceTypes = session.PriceTypes.ToList();

        this.service.Put(model);
    }

    private Query BuildQueryByKeys(string sessionKey, string packageId, string token)
    {
        ...
    }

    private string BuildKey(FlexSession session)
    {
        return session.SessionKey + "|" + session.PackageId + "|" + session.Token;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class Controller
{
    private readonly Repository repository;

    public Controller(Repository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public ActionResult Put(string sessionKey, string packageId, string token, int[] priceTypes)
    {
        var flexSession = this.repository.Get(sessionKey, packageId, token);

        var newFlexSession = flexSession.Create(priceTypes);

        this.repository.Update(newFlexSession);

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

**Domain Model**

```
public class FlexSession
{
    public FlexSession(FlexSessionDocument document)
    {
        var parts = ParseSortKey(document.SortKey);

        SessionKey = parts.Item1;
        PackageId = int.Parse(parts.Item2);
        Token = parts.Item3;

        PriceTypes = document.PriceTypes == null ? ImmutableList.Create<int>() : ImmutableList.Create(document.PriceTypes.ToArray());
    }

    private FlexSession(string sessionKey, int packageId, string token, ImmutableList<int> priceTypes)
    {
        SessionKey = sessionKey;
        PackageId = packageId;
        Token = token;
        PriceTypes = priceTypes;
    }

    public string SessionKey { get; }

    public int PackageId { get; }

    public string Token { get; }

    public ImmutableList<int> PriceTypes { get; }

    public FlexSession Create(int[] priceTypes)
    {
        if (priceTypes.Length > 100)
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid price type quanity");
        }

        var result = new FlexSession(SessionKey, PackageId, Token, ImmutableList.Create(priceTypes));

        return result;
    }

    private Tuple<string, string, string> ParseSortKey(string sortKey)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sortKey))
        {
            throw new Exception($"Invalid flex session sort key value: {sortKey}");
        }

        var keyparts = sortKey.Split('|');

        if (keyparts.Length != 3)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Failed to split the flex session sort key. Value: {sortKey}");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(keyparts[0]))
        {
            throw new Exception($"Invalid flex session sort key, tessitura session key was missing. Value: {sortKey}");
        }

        var sessionKey = keyparts[0];

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(keyparts[1]))
        {
            throw new Exception($"Invalid flex session sort key, package id was missing. Value: {sortKey}");
        }

        var packageId = keyparts[1];

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(keyparts[2]))
        {
            throw new Exception($"Invalid flex session sort key, flex token was missing. Value: {sortKey}");
        }

        var token = keyparts[2];

        return Tuple.Create(sessionKey, packageId, token);
    }
}
```

I saw the ImmutableList has an "Add" function that will return a new list with the new data. Instead of "Create" would a function named "Update" be more appropriate.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3):

A few suggestions in the code. Use Dependency Injection for better test-ability

1. In Controller

   ```
   public class Controller
   {
       private readonly IRepository _repository = null;
       public Controller(IRepository repository)
       {
           this._repository = repository;
       } 
    }
   ```
2. In Repository

   ```
   public class Repository 
   {
       private readonly IService _service;

       public Repository(IService service)
       {
           this.service = service;
       }
   ```
3. In Flex session

   ```
   public class FlexSession
   {
       public FlexSession(IDocument flexSessionDocument)
       {
         ......
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! Since the document is a POCO, is there any benefit to adding IDocument?